# Actual translation especially according Sayanacharya of controversial verses of Shukla Yajurved Book 23, Verses 20-31 regarding Ashwamedha Yajna

Tags: vedas, translation-request, shukla-yajurveda, ashwamedha

The verses, descrbing Ashwamedha Yajna in controversial verses of Shukla Yajurved Book 23, Verses 20-31 is skipped in [English translation.](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/wyv/wyvbk23.htm)

> 19 Thee we invoke, troop-lord of troops, Thee we invoke, the loved
> ones’ lord. Thee, lord of treasures, we invoke. My precious wealth! .
> .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     . .     .
> .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
>
> 32 Now have I
> glorified with praise strong Dadhikrâvan, conquering steed, Sweet may
> he make our mouths: may he prolong the days we have to live.

---

So what is the genuine translation of these skipped [Sanskrit verses](https://vedicheritage.gov.in/samhitas/yajurveda/vajasneyi-madhyandina-samhita/samhita-patha-21-30-adhyaya-23/)? **Especially in the light of Sayanacharya and other traditional commentaries.**

> आहम॑जानि गर्भ॒धमा त्वम॑जासि गर्भ॒धम् ।। १९ ।।
>
> ता उ॒भौ च॒तुर॑: प॒दः सं॒प्रसा॑रयाव स्व॒र्गे लो॒के प्रोर्णु॑वाथां॒ वृषा॑ > वा॒जी रे॑तो॒धा रेतो॑ दधातु ।। २० ।।
>
> उत्स॑क्थ्या॒ अव॑ गु॒दं धे॑हि॒ सम॒ञ्जिं चा॑रया वृषन् ।
> य स्त्री॒णां जी॑व॒भोज॑नः ।। २१ ।।
>
> य॒कास॒कौ श॑कुन्ति॒काऽऽहल॒गिति॒ वञ्च॑ति ।
> आह॑न्ति ग॒भे पसो॒ निग॑ल्गलीति॒ धार॑का ।। २२ ।।
>
> य॒को॒ऽस॒कौ श॑कुन्त॒क आ॒हल॒गिति॒ वञ्च॑ति ।
> विव॑क्षत इव ते॒ मुख॒मध्व॑र्यो॒ मा न॒स्त्वम॒भि भा॑षथाः ।। २३ ।।
>
> मा॒ता च॑ ते पि॒ता च॒ तेऽग्रं॑ वृ॒क्षस्य॑ रोहतः ।
> प्रति॑ला॒मीति॑ ते पि॒ता ग॒भे मु॒ष्टिम॑तᳪसयत् ।। २४ ।।
>
> मा॒ता च॑ ते पि॒ता च॒ तेऽग्रे॑ वृ॒क्षस्य॑ क्रीडतः ।
> विव॑क्षत इव ते॒ मुखं॒ ब्रह्म॒न्मा त्वं व॑दो ब॒हु ।। २५ ।।
>
> ऊ॒र्ध्वमे॑ना॒मुच्छ्रा॑पय गि॒रौ भा॒रᳪ हर॑न्निव ।
> अथा॑स्यै॒ मध्य॑मेधताᳪ शी॒ते वाते॑ पु॒नन्नि॑व ।। २६ ।।
>
> ऊ॒र्ध्वमे॑न॒मुच्छ्र॑यताद्गि॒रौ भा॒रᳪ हर॑न्निव ।
> अथा॑स्य॒ मध्य॑मेजतु शी॒ते वाते॑ पु॒नन्नि॑व ।। २७ ।।
>
> यद॑स्या अᳪहु॒भेद्या॑: कृ॒धु स्थू॒लमु॒पात॑सत् ।
> मु॒ष्काविद॑स्या एजतो गोश॒फे श॑कु॒लावि॑व ।। २८ ।।
>
> यद्दे॒वासो॑ ल॒लाम॑गुं॒ प्र वि॑ष्टी॒मिन॒मावि॑षुः ।
> स॒क्थ्ना दे॑दिश्यते॒ नारी॑ स॒त्यस्या॑क्षि॒भुवो॒ यथा॑ ।। २९ ।।
>
> यद्ध॑रि॒णो यव॒मत्ति॒ न पु॒ष्टं प॒शु मन्य॑ते ।
> शू॒द्रा यदर्य॑जारा॒ न पोषा॑य धनायति ।। ३० ।।
>
> यद्ध॑रि॒णो यव॒मत्ति॒ न पु॒ष्टं ब॒हु मन्य॑ते ।
> शू॒द्रो यदर्या॑यै जा॒रो न पोष॒मनु॑ मन्यते ।। ३१ ।।

Answer (score 1):

Sir I couldn't find actual translation for verses 20-31 by Sir Griffiths,
instead i found translation done by Dr Tulsi Ram from the Arya Samaj.

> 20.Let both of them, the ruler and the people, protect
> and support each other. May both realise and extend
> the four values of life: Dharma, righteous living, Artha,
> worldly well-being, kama, self-fulfilment, and Moksha,
> ultimate freedom. May the ruler, wielder of power, swift
> in action and advancement, strengthen the people with
> power, and the people, in return, strengthen the ruler
> with power.

> 21.O Ruler, man of strength and power, if there is
> anyone evil who plays with the life and honour of
> women, punish him. Establish peace among the people.
> Establish the rule of law. Eliminate immorality and
> wantonness from the state.

> 22.Where the ruler strikes at the people, he strikes at
> the nation and the state because there the people, though
> otherwise they enjoyed comfort and happiness before,
> grow weaker and weaker now and fade like a helpless
> bird. When such a ruler exacts taxes from the farmers,
> he only cheats the nation.

> 23.Ruler, high-priest of the yajna of the state, make no false promises to us. Let your mouth be not like a
> boaster’s. If you tell lies, you will grow weaker and
> weaker like a helpless bird and end up, cheating yourself.

> 24.Ruler, the earth your mother and the sun your father
> rise to the top of the world. The sun strikes at the treasure
> of space-waters with his light and power, the earth
> receives the showers and shines. Celebrate them with
> the people in yajna: It is beautiful, it is joyous. I am happy.

> 25. People of the land, your mother-land like the earth
>     and the ruler, father of the nation, like the sun, both
>     joyous, play on top of the world in the midst of beauty
>     and prosperity. Ruler, Brahma, presiding priest of the
>     national yajna, your mouth seems eager to shout with
>     pride and joy. At that time, speak not much, control
>     yourself.

> 26.Ruler of the land, lead this rising nation to the
> heights of beauty and prosperity like a mountaineer
> bearing his banner to the top of the mount, and, in the
> midst of this people, being sanctified as if in the cool
> mountain breezes, move on higher and ever higher

> 27.Man of knowledge, enlightened citizen, support
> this rising ruler to the height of glory and power as a
> mountaineer carrying his burden to the top of the mount,
> and, in the midst of this nation, and sifting the truth
> from falsehood, as if, in the cool breeze, shine on in the
> beauty and prosperity of the land.

> 28.When the small and great acts of the people who
> clear out sin and crime from the society are appreciated
> by the ruler and the enlightened officers, they, the ruler
> and the elite, captivate the heart of the people and they
> shine in their eyes as shakula fish shine in a little pool
> of water.

> 29.Just as noble people approach an eminent and
> reasonable judge for justice, just as a woman is
> distinguished by her body, so the men of reason find out
> the truth by direct observation of evidence.

> 30.When the deer eats up the barley it does not care
> for the field but destroys it. A servant woman who is
> the mistress of her master loves money but not for the
> well-being of her master or of her family. So when a
> ruler exploits his people, he does not care for their wellbeing, he destroys the nation.

> 31.The deer that eats up the barley cares not for the
> crop and the field. The servant who is a paramour of his
> mistress cares not for the well-being of the family. The
> ruler who exploits the people destroys the nation.

Hope this helps you Sir.If you require any more translations for verses do let me know.
Reference taken from [here.](https://ia800106.us.archive.org/12/items/susmitaroychowdhury512_gmail/%E0%A6%AF%E0%A6%9C%E0%A7%81%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%A6.pdf)

Comment: The translation seems so different than others

Comment: Can you please try to give the translation in the light of Sayanacharya commentry.

Comment: Translation seems different because as you know Sayanacharya's Commentary has been translated into english by Sir Max Muller while Sir Ralph Griffiths consulted the one written by Max Muller for his own translation.
Both Commentaries are based on two different schools of thoughts/methadologies for interpreting Vedas.
Sayanacharya's school was the Yājñikā school: ritualistic or sacrificial method of interpretation
Prof Tulsi Ram is affiliated with the Nairuktā School:etymological school of interpretation which interprets Vedic words on the basis of their derivative connection

Comment: I couldn't find translations by Griffiths/Max Muller on Shukla yajur Veda but found one by AB Keith(closely associated with sir Ralph Griffiths)
part 1 
https://ia800404.us.archive.org/14/items/vedaofblackyajus01keit/vedaofblackyajus01keit.pdf
part 2
https://ia801200.us.archive.org/32/items/vedaofblackyajus02keit/vedaofblackyajus02keit.pdf

Comment: Ok Found the original translation book by griffiths
https://ia802806.us.archive.org/9/items/textswhiteyajur00grifgoog/textswhiteyajur00grifgoog.pdf
See **page 237** He says verses 20-31 are **not** reproducible even in semi-obscurity of a learned european language and verses 30,31 would unintelligible without *these* earlier verses.

Comment: Sir i searched up the internet;These seem like some controversial statements of which some so called scholars have given quite  lewd interpretations.
This might be one of the reasons Sir Ralph Griffiths refused to even translate such verses in english as they result in some form of a twisted meaning if **transliterated**

Comment: Actually Sir i did read a few commentaries on the same part(Hindi translations)
and i found them really satisfactory, but idts you would be able to understand them.English translations just feel like Empty transliterations with no spiritual understanding whatsoever.Even the translations i posted above Prof Tulsi Ram tried his best but couldn't capture the essence of the verses in *English*.
I would also recommend you to learn sanskrit by yourself and not rely on English translation as most of them absolutely fail to capture the immense spiritual knowledge behind each verse.

Comment: Can you edit the answer and the commetaries and translation based on Sayanacharya also?? If they are in Sanskrit and not available in English, then add only Sanskrit verses, so people who can understand it can explain.

Comment: Ok Sir i would try my best to get back to you on this in a few days...One Qn though 
would any other school of thought interpretation for Vedas other than Yājñikā school   
(associated with Sayanacharya) be fine or you want an affiliated one only??

Comment: I don't about these schoolsnof Yajnika and Nirukta. Nirukta based meanings lead people to perform Yajnas. I just consider Sayanacharya as autuentic as he is the one of the very few traditional Acharyas who has written a Bhashya on the Vedas.

Comment: Sir i couldn't find any translation affiliated with Sayanacharya *online*
There may be offline books available.
I did find a lot of hindi transaltions i.e by Swami Dayanand Saraswati ,Hariharanand Saraswati etc.I found also one independent translation done By AB keith in English which is mentioned above.

Comment: I can only provide you with sources for these(also found Sanskrit Bhasya by Bhatta Bhaskara Mishra and Sayanachraya's original one on Taittriya Samhita but the Sanskrit is far too advanced for me to navigate through the chapters).

Comment: I have been strictly advised by my revered guru to **not** engage in giving any person translations on Vedic verses as they are meant to be read Only and Only under a Guru in Sanskrit with proper pronunciations and grammer because the spiritual understanding gets distorted when its not learnt properly and  in another language.Also before learning any Veda first your impure soul must be purified to make it fit to gain the supreme knowledge though proper and guided sadhana,bhakti.

Comment: Also as proper translations arent available only thing i could ultimately do was with my little konwledge translate the hindi bhasya into english;but i have been advised by my guru to not translate with my half-knowledge and mind full of ego.So my final advise would be to find a Guru for yourself Sir **if** you have such an intense desire to learn the Vedas!

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan Whats your take on this, as you have already read the Taittiriya Samhita of Shukla Yajur Veda? Any help/advice would be really appreciated!

Comment: Finding a guru is hard to impossible?